# Determine Apple Watch battery level from paired iPhone

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

On Apple Watch, I'm able to check the battery level and charging state within my WatchKit Extension by setting `WKInterfaceDevice.current().isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true` then checking `WKInterfaceDevice.current().batteryLevel` and `WKInterfaceDevice.current().batteryState`.

While the `WKInterfaceDevice.current()` object is available on iOS, the `isBatteryMonitoringEnabled`, `batteryLevel`, and `batteryState` properties are not.

**Is anyone aware of a way to access a paired Apple Watch's battery level and charging state from iOS?**

It seems like it might be possible since Apple's **Batteries** widget shows the current level and charging state for a paired Apple Watch, although this may be using private APIs since it's a widget built into iOS.

**For more context, see the [post about what I was trying to accomplish on Medium](https://medium.com/@gohnjanotis/apple-watch-battery-level-charging-notifications-eb7d0797a4d8).**

Comment: You can send that information from your `watchOS` app (if you have one) to your `iOS` app using the `WatchConnectivity` framework, but AFAIK there's no other solution using public APIs and without having a connected `watchOS` app.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Yes, that's what I'm doing for now: sending a message from watchOS to iOS with a background task, but the updates are too infrequent to be useful for my needs. It seems the data's already being sent to the iPhone more frequently, so I was hoping to tap into that, but it doesn't seem to be available with public APIs.

Comment: I’m not sure, but probably it can be possible to get battery level of any connected bluetooth device from iPhone just utilizing bluetooth capabilities. So, considering Apple Watch is just another bluetooth device, probably it can be a solution.